# What is the difference between tint and solid in a shape?

Tags: android, android-layout

I saw this item in xml layout:

```
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:tint="#ffff00">
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        <size android:height="4dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ffff00" />
    </shape>
```

So `tint` and `solid` are setting the same color. When I change `solid` to another color, it doesn't have any visible effect, so `solid` seems to be overridden by `tint` anyway.

In my understanding, `solid` defines the fill color of the shape. While `tint` colorizes the whole item in the given color, including for example the stroke color.

What could be the purpose of defining the same color in both items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about that tint will overwrite solid.

Usually I would use solid when define a shape or drawable and use tint to customise it when necessary.

For example, you define your logo in its usual color. In certain screen, you want the logo to fit into the theme of that screen, you can make use of tint.

Note that, tint works not only with solid, you can even tint your image drawable.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but in the example above it wouldn't make any sense, would it?

Answer (score 1):

of course tint will overwrite solid.
when you use a drawable that contains transparent parts, tint just colorizes parts that have color not transparent and solid colorize all the drawable whether its has color or not

Comment: "solid colorize all the drawable whether its has color or not" I think that is misleading at best. `solid` does not colorize, it simply defines the color.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on the usage, that how you are using it. I want to share one example for you.
Let suppose you have one shape or drawable file and you want to use that in 10 different place in different color. so you don't need to add 10 different drawable files in folder, just you can use the same drawable file with `android:tint="your_desired_color"` properties.

In this place tint will be useful, its just like a filter to change the color of that shape or drawables.

Don't be confuse with this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that doesn't address my question. I know what `tint` does, and I can as well change the `solid color` for every drawable instead of tinting it. My question is if there was any purpose of defining both.

Comment: As per your question, their is no purpose of defining the same color in both items.

Comment: The answer does not give new information as relates to my question. If you can add something useful that is not covered by other answers, I will of course upvote it.